# How do I make JRECreate compile a headful JRE?

Tags: java, embedded-linux, armv7

I have an embedded ARMv7 instrument that needs a Soft Floating Point version of Java 8. (If I use a HardFP version, the machine literally acts like it doesn't exist, but a SoftFP version it works fine with.) However, since Java 8, Oracle stopped supplying SoftFP downloads, and instead gave us a "JRECreate" thing that's supposed to be able to fill our needs.

Except I also need a headful (ie, NOT headless) version of the JRE, and for some reason the program only seems to output Headless versions of the JRE, and there doesn't seem to be a way to make it NOT headless. The ["documentation"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/embedded/develop-apps-platforms/jrecreate.htm#CACDGBGB) is useless, of course. Is there any way to do this??

Failing that, where do I find a version of Java to compile myself, since Oracle seems to not want to support what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently including the `lib/arm/libawt_xawt.so` file from another distribution (like the already headful HardFP one) is enough to tell Java to not be in headless mode anymore, and to properly load the awt library.

So for future people suffering this (such as, inevitably, myself when I have to update to Java 9), the difference between headless and headful Java is the presence of a single library file, and you have to Frankenstein parts together to do Oracle's job for them.

Comment: My downloaded JRE for ARM has 'libawt.so' and 'libawt_headless.so' only.Is it possible to show GUI still?

Comment: Did you try? If you try to do anything requiring a head (things like showing or maybe even creating a JFrame), Java will throw a HeadlessException if it can't show a gui. I think even doing things like trying to create a Dimension object can throw HeadlessExceptions.